# Ошибка при генерации CRUD в Symfony2

Tags: php, crud, symfony2

Здравствуйте, проблема при изменении сущности через CRUD в symfony2, сгенерил круд, ничего не трогал, захожу по /admin/post/1/edit получаю ошибку:

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class SomeHelp\UserBundle\Entity\UserEntity. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "SomeHelp\UserBundle\Entity\UserEntity" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class SomeHelp\UserBundle\Entity\UserEntity to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.
```

Я предполагаю что это из-за связного поля

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SomeHelp\UserBundle\Entity\UserEntity",inversedBy="user",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */

protected $user;
```

Что с этим делать? Пожалуйста опишите детально.

Comment: Дело в том что я даже когда комментирую это связное поле в PostType ошибка все равно не пропадает

Comment: дропдаун-меню то что мне нужно. Пробовал настраивать в buildForm поле юзера с entity типом - не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на то. Я сейчас только читаю главу кукбука про формы, но надо либо добавить встроенную (embed) форму (вряд ли желательно - это будет полная форма пользователя), либо заставить форму проигнорировать пользователя, если пользователь всегда проставляется автоматически (поставить полю опцию `'mapped' => false`, если не ошибаюсь), либо сделать дропдаун-меню из пользователей (тут я сам уже не подскажу).

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SomeHelp\UserBundle\Entity\UserEntity",inversedBy="user",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */

protected $user;
```

У вас крайне странно идет связь на User-ов. В поле inversedBy нужно указывать имя филда, по которому доступа зависимая сущность, в вашем случае, я так полагаю, это будет что-то вроде posts.

И можно скинуть полный мапинг сущностей, форму и еще результат команды:

```
$ app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```